# canvas not occupying full space in grid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a canvas in grid. On the mousemove event of canvas i am trying to translate the canvas. It works fine. However my canvas doesn't occupy the full space in the grid. What changes do i need to make in this program so that the canvas occupies the full space.

This is my xaml :-

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightTestCanvasDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Margin="0" Background="Red">
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="84" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is some text to test whether screen is moving" Canvas.Top="99" Height="84" Width="196" FontSize="18.667" FontFamily="Cambria"/>
            </Canvas>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is the code :-

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SilverlightTestCanvasDemo
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        private bool _isDown = false;
        private Point _lastPoint;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            canvas.MouseLeftButtonDown += canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            canvas.MouseLeftButtonUp += canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp;
            canvas.MouseMove += canvas_MouseMove;
        }

        void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_isDown)
            {
                Point point = e.GetPosition(canvas);
                double deltaX = point.X - _lastPoint.X;
                double deltaY = point.Y - _lastPoint.Y;
                CompositeTransform transform = null;
                if (!(canvas.RenderTransform is CompositeTransform))
                {
                    transform = new CompositeTransform();
                    canvas.RenderTransform = transform;
                }
                else
                {
                    transform = canvas.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
                }

                transform.TranslateX += deltaX;
                transform.TranslateY += deltaY;

                //canvas.Height += deltaY;
                //canvas.Width += deltaX;


                _lastPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);
            }
        }

        void canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _isDown = false;
        }

        void canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _isDown = true;
            _lastPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I've reproduced your code and it does what I would expect it to.  Can you describe in more detail what your expectations are? The size of the canvas does fill the Grid.  Of course when its translated you see some of the Grid behind exposed.  Is that not what you were expecting?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones :- Yes it does but i would like the red background to be always filled up. In short i would want the same behavior that you achieve 'by moving(translating) the children inside the canvas but by translating only the canvas not all the children'. You see the red background is always visible if we had translated only the children of the canvas. I want the same effect. I tried increasing the height and width of the canvas along with applying translation but it only works for bottom right corner. It does not work for top-left corner and so you can see white background.

Comment: @@AnthonyWJones:- Please let me know if i am still not clear.

Comment: Yes one thing I'm still not clear on, why not let the canvas be translated and set the background on the Grid as @snowbear suggests?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones:- @Snowbeer is not suggesting to change the background of the grid. He is suggesting to move the mouse event handlers from canvas to grid which is not what i want. Even if i simply change the background of the grid to red to fake the effect it won't work because if the user is on the grid(thinking that it is canvas) he won't be able to drag that part (since it is grid and not canvas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Margin="0" Background="AliceBlue">
        <Canvas>
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="84" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is some text to test whether screen is moving" Canvas.Top="99" Height="84" Width="196" FontSize="18.667" FontFamily="Cambria"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

and tweak the mouse move code behind to this:-

```
   void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isDown)
        {
            Point point = e.GetPosition(canvas);
            double deltaX = point.X - _lastPoint.X;
            double deltaY = point.Y - _lastPoint.Y;
            CompositeTransform transform = null;

            if (!(canvas.Children[0].RenderTransform is CompositeTransform))
            {
                transform = new CompositeTransform();
                canvas.Children[0].RenderTransform = transform;
            }
            else
            {
                transform = canvas.Children[0].RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
            }

            transform.TranslateX += deltaX;
            transform.TranslateY += deltaY;

            _lastPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);
        }
    }
```

What's happening here is a second inner Canvas is being used as a caddy to hold the set of actual children.  Now you need only transform this inner canvas to move all the content about.

Comment: - Excellent! I think this will really improve performance if the innercanvas contains 100's of children. So instead of applying transform to all of them we apply only to one item. What do you think?

Comment: @Kay:  Yes I think applying a single transform is very likely to be quicker than applying 100 of them.